# how can i render next ques based on previous answer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<body>
<div id="hobbie">
  <input type="radio" name="hobbie" value="movie">movie</movie>
  <input type="radio" name="hobbie" value="game">games</movie>
  <input type="radio" name="hobbie" value="sport">sports</movie>
</div>
<hr>
<hr>
<div id="genre">
  <input type="radio" name="movie" value="action">action</movie>
  <input type="radio" name="movie" value="adventure">adventure</movie>
  <input type="radio" name="movie" value="time">time</movie>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="game">
  <input type="radio" name="game" value="gta">GTA</movie>
  <input type="radio" name="game" value="fpp">FPP</movie>
  <input type="radio" name="game" value="sports">sport</movie>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="sport">
  <input type="radio" name="sport" value="cricket">cricket</movie>
  <input type="radio" name="sport" value="football">football</movie>
  <input type="radio" name="sport" value="tennis">tennis</movie>
</div>
<hr>
<hr>
</body>
```

> above I wrote HTML code for different interest and the input type is radio button to select

> I want a javascript/jquery code that gets the radio I choose and based on that next question should be render
> for example, if I choose the movie so div with genre id should render next

> I hope you get my question sorry if asked not in an ordinary manner, can anyone help me out

Comment: First you are ending all the inputs with `</movie>` Second your `<input type="radio" name="hobbie" value="movie">` refers to `movie` but there is no `#movie` but only `#genre`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example of this could be something like:

```
$('#game,#movie,#sport').hide();
$('#hobbie input').change(function() {
  $('#game,#movie,#sport').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
})
```

But as I wrote in the comments there are a few problems with your code that you should addres.

Also I advice you to use label combined with the input so you can click on the text and not only the radio button.

like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="inputmovie" name="hobbie" value="movie">
<label for="inputmovie" >movie</label
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#game,#movie,#sport').hide();
$('#hobbie input').change(function() {
  $('#game,#movie,#sport').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hobbie">
  <input type="radio" name="hobbie" value="movie">movie
  <input type="radio" name="hobbie" value="game">games
  <input type="radio" name="hobbie" value="sport">sports
</div>
<hr>
<hr>
<div id="movie">
  <input type="radio" name="movie" value="action">action
  <input type="radio" name="movie" value="adventure">adventure
  <input type="radio" name="movie" value="time">time
</div>
<hr>
<div id="game">
  <input type="radio" name="game" value="gta">GTA
  <input type="radio" name="game" value="fpp">FPP
  <input type="radio" name="game" value="sports">sport
</div>
<hr>
<div id="sport">
  <input type="radio" name="sport" value="cricket">cricket
  <input type="radio" name="sport" value="football">football
  <input type="radio" name="sport" value="tennis">tennis
</div>
```